# WebRTC, getDisplayMedia(), не захватывает звук удаленного стрима

Tags: javascript, потоки-данных, webrtc, webapi

Всех приветствую!
Есть собственное WebRTC приложение на основе peerjs, - видео конференции.
Пытаюсь реализовать запись средствами MediaRecorder и столкнулся с неприятным моментом.
Беру стрим рабочего стола вот таким образом

```
let chooseScreen = document.querySelector('.chooseScreenBtn')
chooseScreen.onclick = async () => {
    let desktopStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video:true, audio: true });
}
```

Далее полученный desktopStream я благополучно визуализирую в DOM теге

```
const videoElement = document.querySelector('.videoElement')
      videoElement.srcObject = desktopStream 
      videoElement.muted = false;
      videoElement.onloadedmetadata = ()=>{videoElement.play();}
```

Предположим я получаю **desktopStream** на странице активной конференции, где все друг друга слышат и видят.

Что бы проверить **desktopStream** я запускаю в соседней вкладке youtube видео и благополучно его слышу и вижу в **videoElement**, однако остальное **аудио** от участников конференции в этот **desktopStream** не попадает.
Разумеется **MediaRecorder** который принимает первым параметром целевой стрим, запишет видео где звука от участников нет, но звук с рабочего стола есть. Такое поведение характерно если получать desktopStream там же где идет конференция, если вынести функциональность на другу страницу, то захватывается звук как нужно.  Даже не знаю куда копать, может подскажет кто-нибудь дельный совет? Если нужно дополнительно выложить код, разумеется выложу.

Answer (score -1):

Если конференция имеет несколько участников (больше 2-ух), лучше подумать о использовании медиа сервера, и так же там ты сможешь записать и обьеденить несколько стримов, janus или kurento, лучше janus, так как у kurento есть проблемы с задержкой и многопоточностью

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).